# Selenium with Python - Switching to main content after popup overlay

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After handling a pop up overlay the rest of the code no longer works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://www.vapordna.com/login.asp')

#handling popup

browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.age-verify-button.age-modal__btn.btn.btn-primary").click()
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Yes").click()
```

If I don't close the pop up the rest of the code works, if I close the popup none of the code after that point works.

```
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_name("email")
emailElem.send_keys("****@****.com")
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
passwordElem.send_keys("******")
passwordElem.submit()
```

I have tried adding this line but it doesn't help,

```
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

To my understanding the popup isn't in a new iframe or window so I'm not sure why there would be any problem with continuing to interact with the page.

I also tried clicking on the body before continuing

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body").click()
```

Comment: what did you mean by “ no longer can interact with the page?"

Comment: When I try to fill in the login form nothing happens. When I run the code without closing the popup first it logs in. The popup creates problems on later pages so I need to close it.

Comment: I have given the answer try with it and let me know..

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your website I observe this is neither an frame nor a window, I just a form so there is **no need** to use here `browser.switchTo().defaultContent();` which actually using for switching from any frame to default, Actually when you are going to find this button on the opened popup which overlay all the page, It would not be full loaded on the page, so you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until this button visible on the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.vapordna.com/login.asp')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.age-verify-button.age-modal__btn.btn.btn-primary"))).click()
```

Now after clicking on this agreement button you can proceed further steps for login.

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't work unfortunately. My code is successful in closing the popup, it's the next part that doesn't work. I've edited my question to make it a bit clearer.